# Unity Doesn't add as much force as coded too

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this may be a dumb question, but when I do the w/s keys, the player object barely moves. it moves, but just a tiny but. my code is pretty much the exact same for the a/d keys, and those keys work fine and propel the player as intended. It logically does not make sense. Did I change a setting to do this? please let me know.

Code:

```
void FixedUpdate() // FixedUpdate() is better with unity's physics engine.
{ 
    if (Input.GetKey("d"))
    {
       rb.AddForce(100, 0, 0 * Time.deltaTime); 
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("a"))
    {
       rb.AddForce(-100, 0, 0 * Time.deltaTime); 
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("s"))
    {
       rb.AddForce(0, 0, -100 * Time.deltaTime); 
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("w"))
    {
       rb.AddForce(0, 0, 100 * Time.deltaTime); 
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("space"))
    {
       rb.AddForce(0, 40, 0 * Time.deltaTime); 
    }
}
```

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/530478/is-it-even-necessary-to-multiply-by-timedeltatime.html

Comment: Hoping you know that `0 * Time.deltaTime` is zero. In order for those calls to be the same it would need to be `rb.AddForce(100 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);`. Since you've said that `100, 0, 0` works and `0, 0, <much smaller number than 100>` does not you'll want to remove all of the multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

**Rigidbody.AddForce()** by default, will apply the force given relative to the Fixed Time.deltaTime. <s>Meaning that your force is already being multiplied by Time.deltaTime.</s> *Meaning, AddForce() is called in a fixed delta time step and is already accounted for*, and you do not need to add it within Rigidbody.AddForce() unless you are using the overload AddForce(Vector3 force, ForceMode mode = ForceMode.Force), and are using a different ForceMode.

Therefore as an example within your code, instead of using:

```
if (Input.GetKey("s"))
{
   rb.AddForce(0, 0, -100 * Time.deltaTime); 
}
```

feel free to use

```
if (Input.GetKey("s"))
{
   rb.AddForce(0, 0, -100); 
}
```

(Edited after **derHugo**'s comment on the way AddForce() is called)

Comment: `Meaning that your force is already being multiplied by Time.deltaTime` that's not entirely true as it stands. What happens is rather that no `Time.deltaTime` is needed at all since `FixedUpdate` already is called in fixed realtime delta steps so it already **is** frame-rate independent anyway